# BillingFlowParams.Builder setSkuDetails for testing static Google Play Billing responses

Tags: android, play-billing-library

I'm testing in-app purchase using the three reserved product IDs for testing static Google Play Billing [responses](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing):

- android.test.purchased
- android.test.canceled
- android.test.item_unavailable

However, `setSku` and `setType` seem to be deprecated in the `BillingFlowParams.Builder` [class](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingFlowParams.Builder). Instead, we should be using `setSkuDetails(SkuDetails)`.

How should I change the `BillingFlowParams` in the example code to use `SkuDetails` for the test product IDs?

```
BillingFlowParams flowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
     .setSku(skuId)
     .setType(SkuType.INAPP) 
     .build();
int responseCode = mBillingClient.launchBillingFlow(flowParams);
```

Comment: Both the question and answers are outDated. BillingFlowParams is not used directly, and instead of returning responseCode, BillingResult is returned in response now. The latest answer hence is quite close to the answer therefore.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

you should get SkuDetails from BillingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync, the sample code may seems like this:

```
private BillingClient mBillingClient;

// ....

mBillingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this).setListener(new PurchasesUpdatedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPurchasesUpdated(int responseCode, @Nullable List<Purchase> purchases) {
        if (responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK
                && purchases != null) {

            // do something you want

        } else if (responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.USER_CANCELED) {
        } else {
        }
    }
}).build();


mBillingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onBillingSetupFinished(@BillingClient.BillingResponse int billingResponseCode) {        

if (billingResponseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK) {
        // The billing client is ready. You can query purchases here.

List<String> skuList = new ArrayList<>();
        skuList.add("android.test.purchased");

SkuDetailsParams skuDetailsParams = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder()
                    .setSkusList(skuList).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP).build();
mBillingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(skuDetailsParams,
                    new SkuDetailsResponseListener() {
 @Override
  public void onSkuDetailsResponse(int responseCode, List<SkuDetails> skuDetailsList) {

  BillingFlowParams flowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                                    .setSkuDetails(skuDetailsList.get(0))
                                    .build();
  int billingResponseCode = billingClient.launchBillingFlow(SkuActivity.this, flowParams);
  if (billingResponseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK) {
                                // do something you want
                            }
                        }
                    });
                 }
               }


@Override
    public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
        // Try to restart the connection on the next request to
        // Google Play by calling the startConnection() method.
    }
});
```

You can also take a look to https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview

Comment: @Ping, beware, google has update it's sample code. The code above MAY not work correctly, you should refer to the latest version.

Comment: @Renkuei +1 for the concise answer, however, the link you provided (at least by the time of posting this comment) also uses the deprecated setSku instead of the setSkuDetails, which I believe is the point of the whole question.

Comment: The example from Google mentioned (Link von Renkuei) still is not up to date. Could Google please check all examples when they are changing the library?

Comment: Quit correction in the code "enablePendingPurchases()." will be needed.

Comment: don't forget to add `.enablePendingPurchases()` when building a `billingClient` instance

Comment: @KirillKarmazin is there anything special that's got to be implemented in order to support that `.enablePendingPurchases()` ? I haven't seen anything, so just checking...

Comment: I guess `.enablePendingPurchases()` is not required for Subscriptions. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: I get the error: "Expected 2 parameters of types Int, (Mutable)List<SkuDetails!>!" at the SkuDetailsResponseListener begin curly brackets. and SkuDetailsResponseListener() itself says: "Redundant SAM-constructor". I also tried the developer page, but withContext, Dispatchers, and querySkuDetails become "Unresolved References"

Comment: how to use getIntroductoryPrice() with this sample , help needed !!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting a step by step process for in-app billing, which I had tested recently after the release of Billing Library version 4.0

Google help resource can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate)

**First things first:** Update your `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    def billing_version = "4.0.0"

    implementation "com.android.billingclient:billing:$billing_version"
}
```

Now, comes the coding part: `BillingActivity.java`

```
private BillingClient mBillingClient;

// ...


submitButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    mBillingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this).enablePendingPurchases().setListener(new PurchasesUpdatedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPurchasesUpdated(BillingResult billingResult, List<Purchase> purchases) {
            if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK
                    && purchases != null) {
                for (Purchase purchase : purchases) {
                    handlePurchase(purchase);
                }
                // Perform your Successful Purchase Task here 
                
                Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Great!! Purchase Flow Successful! :)", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                dismiss();
            } else if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.USER_CANCELED) {
                // Handle an error caused by a user cancelling the purchase flow.
                Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "User Cancelled the Purchase Flow!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                // Handle any other error codes.
                Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Error! Purchase Task was not performed!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }).build();

    mBillingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {

        @Override
        public void onBillingSetupFinished(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult) {

            if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                // The BillingClient is ready. You can query purchases here.

                List<String> skuList = new ArrayList<>();
                skuList.add("billing_template_1");
                skuList.add("billing_template_2");
                SkuDetailsParams.Builder params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder();
                params.setSkusList(skuList).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP);
                mBillingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params.build(),
                        new SkuDetailsResponseListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSkuDetailsResponse(BillingResult billingResult,
                                                             List<SkuDetails> skuDetailsList) {
                                // Process the result.
                                // Retrieve a value for "skuDetails" by calling querySkuDetailsAsync().
                                BillingFlowParams billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                                        .setSkuDetails(skuDetailsList.get(0))
                                        .build();
                                int responseCode = mBillingClient.launchBillingFlow(activity, billingFlowParams).getResponseCode();
                            }
                        });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
            // Try to restart the connection on the next request to Google Play by calling the startConnection() method.
            Toast.makeText(BillingActivity.this, "Service Disconnected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
});
        
void handlePurchase(Purchase purchase) {
    ConsumeParams consumeParams =
            ConsumeParams.newBuilder()
                    .setPurchaseToken(purchase.getPurchaseToken())
                    .build();

    ConsumeResponseListener listener = new ConsumeResponseListener() {
        @Override
        public void onConsumeResponse(BillingResult billingResult, @NonNull String purchaseToken) {
            if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                // Handle the success of the consume operation.
            }
        }
    };
    mBillingClient.consumeAsync(consumeParams, listener);
}
    
    
private void dismiss() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        finish();
    }
```

**FYI:**

- This is just an updated version to @Renkuei answer posted.
- Don't forget `.enablePendingPurchase()`
- Don't forget `skuList.add("billing_template_1")` which has to be done from your Developer Console. So, `billing_template_1` is the name of your *Monetise > Products > In-app products > Prouduct ID*